# A dominating $\sigma$-finite measure for all conditional distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two real-valued random variables with a specified joint probability distribution $P_{X,Y}.$ I wish to determine if there is a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on the real line such that $P_{Y|X=x} << \mu$ for $P_X$-almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Call this property $Q.$ Property $Q$ does not always hold eg. if $X$ is standard normal and $Y=X.$

Is there an equivalent description of property $Q$ that is easy to check for a given probability distribution $P_{X,Y}$?